# SQL Server CASE statement error: Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, case

I am trying to convert:

- any number less than 0 to a -1.
- any number greater than or equal to 0 to a 1.

My statement is:

```
SUM(CASE [Apr] WHEN ([Apr] < 0) THEN -1 WHEN ([Apr] >= 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Apr
```

`[Apr]` is an int which accepts Nulls.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `[Apr]` after `CASE` when doing comparisions in `WHEN`

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ([Apr] < 0) THEN -1 WHEN ([Apr] >= 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Apr
```

Answer (score 1):

Get ride of the [Apr] after CASE.

Answer (score 1):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ([Apr] < 0) THEN -1 WHEN ([Apr] >= 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Apr
```

Lose the [Apr] after **Case**